# Drawable xml issue: corner radius not working

Tags: android, xml, drawable

Due to a bug in my app on android 4.4, I had to change some of my xml drawable files.
Now I have this xml file that I use to give a background color and to round the corners:

My xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

The problem is that my corners are not rounded at all!
Note that if I remove this attribute of the "item" tag:

```html
android:drawable="@android:color/white"
```

it works.
But obiouvsly the background color is gone. I also underline that I cannot use this method:

```html
<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
```

This because for some unknown reasons it crashes on android 4.4 (as I said on top).

Does anyone know why corners aren't rounded and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does  `<solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>` work without crashing?

Comment: No, it crashes... I don't know why, but I found that android:color (in drawable xml only), makes the app crash when the drawable is assigned and used..

Comment: try shape instead of selector. and shape is whatever u want ex. rectangle . oval etc.